# Is $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdots\sin x\cdots\right)\right)=\frac4{\pi}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\sin(2k+1)x}{2k+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, fourier-series

We can see intuitively that
$$
f(x)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdots\sin{x}\cdots\right)\right)\right)
$$
is the square wave with period $2\pi$ and has the value $0$ at the jumps, i.e
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } \frac{x}{\pi}\in\mathbb{Z}\\
\mathrm{sign}(\sin{x}) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Look at this graph of $x$ and $\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}x}$ to see why :

[image: Graph of x and sin(pi/2*x)]

But $f(x)$ is then also exactly equal to the Fourier series of the square wave with period $2\pi$ since Dirichlet conditions assure that the series converges to $0$ (the midpoint) at the jumps as do $f(x)$.

Hence we might be able to show that, 
$$
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdots\sin{x}\cdots\right)\right)\right)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{(2k+1)x}}{2k+1}
$$

Does anyone have an idea of how to prove this directly? Are there other Fourier series that are equal to a recursive formula of trigonometric functions?

Restated, the problem is to show that if
$$
f_0(x)=\sin{x},\quad\text{and}\quad f_n(x)=\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}f_{n-1}(x)\right)}
$$
then,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{f_n(x)}=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{(2k+1)x}}{2k+1}
$$

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on the meaning of "directly". This seems pretty direct to me, and I'm having a hard time imagining how it might be shown even more directly.

Comment: @joriki By *directly*, I meant cleverly use known identities to see why the equality holds without having to state that both are the square wave. Why I asked this question is because I think that it could bring light on the connection between recurrence relation of trigonometric functions and Fourier series which might gives us insight of how to find other similar identities.

Comment: [This paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01450008) might have something useful...

Comment: Thanks @J.M.. Unfortunately, my current lack of knowledge of the German language makes it hard for me to extract useful information. Do they investigate this kind of question in the paper?

Comment: New remark : $\frac{4}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{4}{\pi}\arctan(\cdots\sin x\cdots)\right)$ works also. In fact, any $g(x)$ satisfying $x<g(x)<1$ for $0<x<1$, $-1<g(x)<x$ for $-1<x<0$ and $g(-1)=-1$, $g(0)=0$, $g(1)=1$ will work with $g(g(g(\cdots\sin x\cdots)))$. Can we find similar conditions for other Fourier Series? The sawtooth wave for example?

Comment: I like the "current" in "current lack of knowledge" :-) "Über die Iteration der ganzen transzendenten Funktionen, insbesondere von $\sin z$ und $\cos z$" means "On the iteration of the entire transcendental functions, in particular of $\sin z$ and $\cos z$" -- but you may have guessed as much already. I don't have free access to the rest of the paper.

Comment: The paper seems to be concerned mainly with properties of the set of points you get when iterating. As far as I can tell, the results are not of use for the question here.

Comment: @joriki: late but... J.M.'s (well Töpfer's) paper at [gdz](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0117&DMDID=DMDLOG_0009&IDDOC=37617)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can easily compute $\mathcal F{\left( f \circ f \right)}$ from $\mathcal F{(f)}$, where $\mathcal F$ is the Fourier transform.

But you can prove the statement above ($f^n$ means $f \circ \cdots \circ f$, $n$-times):

$$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} f^n(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } \frac{x}{\pi}\in\mathbb{Z}\\
\mathrm{sign}(\sin{x}) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

And then deduce:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{f^n(x)}=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{(2k+1)x}}{2k+1}
$$
$f(x) = \sin( \frac{\pi}{2} x) $ sends $[-1,1]$ onto itself, it has $3$ fixed points: $-1, 0$ and $1$.

The derivative at these points is respectively: $0, \frac{\pi}{2} > 1$ and $0$. So $-1$ and $1$ are super-attracting fixed points (any point close to $-1$ or $1$ move closer and closer) whereas $0$ is repelling fixed point (any point close to $0$ move away).

If $0 < x < 1$, $f^n(x) \to 1$ (very fast) and if $-1 < x < 0$, $f^n(x) \to -1$.

I can give more details, if needed.